# D3.JS - Generate a range of dates between DateA & DateB

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, range, scale

I need to generate a scale, for reference in my application, of dates between for example, 01/01/2001 - 30/11/2001.

I need to be able to pass an int (between 1-10) into the scale and have a date returned back.

I am assuming D3.JS can do this as it can generate a scale of dates for an axis no problem.

I have tried:

```
myDateScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([1,10])
            .range([d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.date}), d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.date})]);
```

When I try and reference this scale like: myDateScale(1), I just get an empty Object{}?!

I have tried changing the scale to d3.time.scale() but still the same result.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

Not sure why the above doesn't work like other scales (numbers, colors etc) but nevermind.

So we need to swap the .domain & .range of for each other, and then use **.invert** to get dates returned.

```
myDateScale = d3.time.scale()
.range([d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.date}), d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.date})])
    .domain([1,10]);

myDateScale.invert(5); // returns a date midway between dateA & dateB
```

Comment: if you flip range and domain, you shouldn't need to use invert.